UPS negotiated rates backend unable to process shipping rate
I have negotiated shipping rates with UPS.  In order to populate those rates in the frontend  I need to use my shipping number, which is in this format XXX-XXXXXX.  All goes well, and my customers can process the cart and shipping amount at the negotiated rate.  However, in the backend when I go to populate a shipment, I receive an error.  The log states that it is a shipping number issue.  I can switch to my normal six digit shipper number in the backend, and then it will process that shipment and generate the label at the negotiated rate.  I'm using Magento 2.4.7 with the stock UPS module.  Has anyone experienced this issue?

I am also struggling with configuring UPS shipping method in magento 2.4.7, did you configure UPS Rest Api?

I don't think this question is related to the topic regarding negotiated rates.  As for the UPS configuration, this will help https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/373149/86525
